# Programming many Atmega328p at once for mass production

Tags: arduino, programming, production

How can I program multiple ATmega328p at once?

Like, for example, the Arduino Uno. How do they program it for mass manufacturing production?

Comment: If you order enough ATMega328 chips at Atmel and pay for the programming they will do it for you with the code you supply them. In the factory a special "programmer" is used, probably it is part of the testing procedure. After testing and the chip has tested OK, it is programmed. I am unsure what you mean by "at once" programming.

Comment: you can use In Circuit Serial Programming or ICSP pins to program them.

Answer (score 3):

To program in-circuit, you can also use either a [JTAG-Connector](https://www.segger.com/fileadmin/images/products/J-Link/J-Link-Edu-Mini/J-Link_EDU_Mini_500x307.png) - as seen on the J-Link Mini, or an on-PCB connector - as you can see on this [tinyK22](https://mcuoneclipse.files.wordpress.com/2018/03/tinyk22-with-usb-hid-bootloader1.png) microprocessor that's used at my university quite a lot. You can see the connectors next to the "K20" and "K22" print. The cable to plug this in is fairly expensive, but it allows you to program a board that only has the 'connector' implemented on the PCB.

Rather than downloading through the IDE, you'd download using a standalone flashing program.

If your quantities are high enough, just as the others said, you'd use preprogrammed chips from the factory.

Comment: Just to give it a name: Looks like a Tag-Connect header on the tinyK22 board you’ve shown.

Answer (score 2):

Arduino exposes all the pins needed for "high voltage" parallel programming on the pin headers. This is faster than ICSP and probably how they are programmed in production, unless pre-programmed chips are used.

However the terminals needed for ICSP are also available so for low volumn production that's an option too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the original arduino uno type chip, you can swap the chips or even get a ZIF socket for easier insertion and removal

[image]

<sub>Image source: [Universal Solder - CANADUINO ZIF Socket Programming Shield V2 for Arduino](https://www.universal-solder.ca/product/canaduino-zif-socket-arduino-programming-shield/)</sub>

You can also pay atmel/supplier to program it for you

Answer (score 1):

If you do high volume production, the boards are assembled and tested automatically, so you already have a production step where voltage is applied to the board at selected spots.

Programming the board at this stage is just a matter of connecting to the appropriate pads for half a second, that is barely noticeable compared to the time that is spent testing for soldering defects.